Return Email Address from SharePoint People/Group using GraphAPI
I am using Microsoft GraphAPI to query a SharePoint list.  The list has a field called Buyer.  When I query a record for that buyer field, what is returned is a number associated with the user in the list permissions.
$ListitemConnection = Get-MgSiteListItem -SiteId $siteId -ListId $listId -ListItemId $ItemId -ExpandProperty "fields" -Property *
        $ListitemDetails = $ListitemConnection.Fields.AdditionalProperties
        $BuyerID = $ListitemDetails.BuyerLookupId

So in the above code $BuyerID will return a number such as "45".  I would like to convert that number to the person's email address but am unsure how.  I looked at the Get-MgUser command but that does not use the PropertyNameLookupID to find the user.
In case it matters, I am connecting to graph using an Azure appID/secret and our tenant.
Connect-MgGraph -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential -TenantId $TenantID -NoWelcome

I would prefer to stick to a solution that only uses GraphAPI and does not require the use of PNP.PowerShell.
Can anyone offer a suggestion?

After a lot of seraching I finally found what I needed.
        $ItemID = $Listitem.Id
        $ListitemConnection = Get-MgSiteListItem -SiteId $siteId -ListId $listId -ListItemId $ItemId -ExpandProperty "fields" -Property *
        $ListitemDetails = $ListitemConnection.Fields.AdditionalProperties
        $BuyerID = $ListitemDetails.BuyerLookupId
        # Get the User Information List
        $UserList = Get-MgSiteList -SiteId $SiteID -Filter "DisplayName eq 'User Information List'" -Select Id
        # Get the user details using the LookupId
        $User = Get-MgSiteListItem -SiteId $SiteID -ListId $UserList.Id -ListItemId $BuyerID -Select "fields" -ExpandProperty "fields"
        # Extract the email address
        $BuyerEmail = $User.Fields.AdditionalProperties.UserName


Thank you for sharing. You can mark it as the answer to help others find the solution more easily.
